# Quick way to run large .sql file using sql developer tool

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

in .sql file i have 90 laksh insertion statements, file even not opening in text editor. While running it is getting very slow and after it is stuck. can anyone provide solution steps.

Comment: Do you have to load data this way?  It would make far more sense (and be far more efficient) to generate a flat file of data (such as a comma-separated file) and use `SQL*Loader` to load the data (assuming the data is coming from a non-Oracle database) or to use the Oracle export and import (original or DataPump) tools to move data from one Oracle database to another.  A file of millions of individual `insert` statements that each need to get hard parsed is one of the least efficient ways to load data.

Answer (score 1):

Run the file as a script instead of loading the file into the IDE. For example:

```
@C:\directory\your_file.sql
```

It may also help to run `set feedback off;` first, to suppress some of the output. If SQL Developer is still slow, try using SQL*Plus instead.

As Justin pointed out, there are better options for loading large amounts of data into Oracle. But if this is a just a one-time process, then it's probably not worth switching methods.